# Overriding property setter

Tags: c#, properties, overriding

I'm making a program where there are some balls bouncing around,  but now I want to inherit that class and make that new one impossible to set it's velocity

i've tried this but that doesn't do anyting

```
public class Ball {
    public Ball(double posX, double posY, double rad, Vector vel) {
        Pos = new Point(posX, posY);
        Rad = rad;
        Vel = vel;
    }
    public double Rad { get; set; }

    public Point Pos { get; set; }
    public Vector Vel { get; set; }
}

public class StaticBall : Ball {
    public StaticBall(double posX, double posY, double rad) 
        : base(posX, posY, rad, new Vector(0, 0)) { 
    }
    public Vector Vel {
        get { return Vel; }
        set { Vel = Vel; }
    }
}
```

how should I do this?

Comment: Remove the property (`public Vector Vel`) from StaticBall and use the one in the base directly.

Comment: If I would remove it, I won't be able to make normal balls :)

Comment: The `public Vector Vel` property is inherited to the child classes, so you can use them and set them in the child class. What do you mean?

Comment: Ow read it wrong, but I just have a large list of balls and static balls, if I would remove the property, then I would have to check if it is an static one or not when I set the velocity in a bounce

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You are setting the velocity here `base(posX, posY, rad, new Vector(0, 0)` in StaticBall constructor. It's set on the base class, but will be used by your StaticBall class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm making a program where there are some balls bouncing around, but now I want to inherit that class and make that new one impossible to set it's velocity

Your requirement violates the [Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If the velocity of a `Ball` can be changed, the velocity of any class inheriting from `Ball` must also be changeable.

Solution: Instead of inheriting `ConstantSpeedBall` from `Ball`, create a new base class `BallBase` and inherit both `ConstantSpeedBall` and `ChangingVelocityBall` from it.

Comment: Ow, woops :p
gonna make the bassBall